# Rails unable to access instance variable in .js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making an ajax request and when it's complete i'm trying to add a div to the page. For some reason, i am unable to get instance variables to work in a .js.erb file.

I have this controller method that gets called

```
 # PUT /applications/1
  # PUT /applications/1.json
  def update
    @application = Application.find(params[:id])
    @current_app = params[:application]
    @curr_app_id = params[:id]
    @current_app.values.each do |key, val|
        key.values.each do |k,v|
            @curr_app_field_name = k[:field_name]
            @curr_app_field_value = k[:field_type]
        end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @application.update_attributes(params[:application])
        format.html { redirect_to @application, notice: 'Application was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

which renders this .js.erb file

```
console.log('name = '+<%= escape_javascript @curr_app_field_name %>); // line 1
console.log('test'); // line 2
```

But when i leave the instance variable in there, i don't get any output in firebug. I can see in the post request that the console.logs get generated with the correct field name, but nothing appears in the firebug console.

If i remove line 1 completely, it works.

How can i make it so i can access some variables in a .js.erb file?

Comment: You are currently overriding the  @curr_app_field_name in loop. Try to inspect whether the last element in the loop is not blank or nil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing Javascript and Ruby incorrectly.

Instead of:

```
console.log('name = '+<%= escape_javascript @curr_app_field_name %>);
```

you have to do this:

```
console.log('name = <%= escape_javascript @curr_app_field_name %>');
```

**Explanation:**

Suppose `@curr_app_field_name == 'foo'` then your current code will evaluate to:

```
console.log('name = '+foo);
```

but the variable foo doesn't exist and will therefore throw an error. If you do it like I suggest it will evaluate to:

```
console.log('name = foo');
```

and everything will work as expected.

Comment: This also works

    console.log('name = '+ <%= raw @curr_app_field_name)

Especially useful if you want to do something like:

    console.log('name = '+ <%= raw JSON.dump(@application.errors) %>)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add quotes like this:

```
console.log('name = '+ "<%= escape_javascript @curr_app_field_name %>");
```

But if it was just that you may have an error in firebug.